# Why does Jest rise this error while testing `Colyseus` game?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, jestjs

I am testing a game functionality with `Jest` as a testing framework and assertion library.
This is my test setup:

```js
const { Server } = require("colyseus")
const { ColyseusTestServer, boot } = require("@colyseus/testing");
const Game = require("./index");

describe("Game", () => {
    let colyseus;
    let TestServer = new Server()
    TestServer.define("my_game", Game)
    const User_1 = {
        key: "token_header.token_payload.and_oh"
    }
    beforeAll(async () => colyseus = await boot(TestServer));
    afterAll(async () => await colyseus.shutdown());
    beforeEach(async () => await colyseus.cleanup());

    test("Should connect", async () => {
        try {
         // `room` is the server-side Room instance reference.
         const room = await colyseus.sdk.joinOrCreate("my_game", {...User_1});

         await room.waitForNextPatch();
         await room.waitForNextMessage();

         // `client1` is the client-side `Room` instance reference (same as JavaScript SDK)
     
         // make your assertions
         expect(room.sessionId).toEqual(room.clients[0].sessionId);
        } catch(err) {
            console.log("errr",err)
        }
    })
})
```

So every time that I run my tests `Jest` logs these `errors`:

```js
Game
    ✕ Should connect (8003 ms)

  ● Game › Should connect

    TypeError: decode[type] is not a function

      at decodePrimitiveType (node_modules/@colyseus/schema/src/Schema.ts:109:34)
      at _.Object.<anonymous>.Schema.decode (node_modules/@colyseus/schema/src/Schema.ts:352:25)
      at SchemaSerializer.Object.<anonymous>.SchemaSerializer.setState (node_modules/colyseus.js/src/serializer/SchemaSerializer.ts:10:20)
      at Room.Object.<anonymous>.Room.setState (node_modules/colyseus.js/src/Room.ts:225:25)
      at Room.Object.<anonymous>.Room.onMessageCallback (node_modules/colyseus.js/src/Room.ts:203:18)
      at WebSocket.onMessage (node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
      at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:983:20)
      at Receiver.dataMessage (node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:502:14)
      at Receiver.getData (node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:435:17)
      at Receiver.startLoop (node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:143:22)
      at Receiver._write (node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:78:10)
      at Socket.socketOnData (node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:1077:35)

  ● Game › Should connect

    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."

      18 |     beforeEach(async () => await colyseus.cleanup());
      19 |     jest.setTimeout(8000)
    > 20 |     test("Should connect", async () => {
         |     ^
      21 |         try {
      22 |             // `room` is the server-side Room instance reference.
      23 |         const room = await colyseus.sdk.joinOrCreate("my_game", {...User_1});

      at server/test.js:20:5
      at Object.<anonymous> (server/test.js:7:1)
      at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
      at runJest (node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:401:19)
      at _run10000 (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:320:7)
      at runCLI (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:173:3)
```

I changed the `timeouts` for `Jest` but it did not change anything.

These are versions for `Colyseus`, `Jest`, and `Node.js` which I am using:

```
"@colyseus/schema": "^1.0.28",
"@colyseus/testing": "^0.14.22",
"colyseus": "^0.14.18",
"jest": "^27.3.1"

node: v14.7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to an undetermined field type of the synced `state`'s `schema` of `colyseus` game framework that had been added to the last versions of the framework. so I just defined the type as `playerId: [string]` and It resolved without any error.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving it there for those struggling with timeout problems (which I had while testing). Mostly it's when no patch is sent after waitForNextPatch() is called, in my case it was either because

- nothing has changed
- problem at patch sending / serialisation: considering your other issue it's probably was why you had a timeout exception
- some weird async situation, calling waitForXXX() too late while the patch has already passed. Unlikely when using in testing situation like this and no real network is involved